# Google app engine cron scheduler is not using synchronized

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I want to run a cron for every 2 minutes interval, 0,2,4,6,8 .... each cron execution runs for 2 minutes.

I configured cron schedule with synchronized as below. But I still see scheduler is behaving as if synchronized not given.

Crons are scheduled at

0-2 First cron

4-6 Second cron

8-10 third cron

Cron scheduler is waiting for 2 minutes after last cron execution.

If I understand synchronized correctly, it is added to avoid this behavior.

Why this happening.

```
  <cron>
  <url>/cron/syncPrices</url>
    <description>Fetch data from source and cache it in data store.</description>
    <schedule>every 2 minutes synchronized</schedule>
  </cron>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the actual cron configuration for your application on the [old GAE console](https://appengine.google.com/) in the **Cron Jobs** menu on the left. You're looking to confirm if `synchronized` (or its `from 00:00 to 23:59` equivalent) is present for the respective job:

- if `synchronized` is missing it's possible that the cron.yaml file wasn't uploaded/updated during the regular app upload - I noticed this to be the case with my multi-module (python) application. You have to specifically update the cron configuration using the `update_cron` option of your AppCfg utility.
- if `synchronized` is indeed present and the unexpected behaviour continues you should open a support case with Google.

Comment: my understanding of literal 'synchronized' is same as OP. for example i want to run a cron every 5 minutes. But my cron would take 10 minutes to complete. without 'synchronized', the expected behavior is first cron starts at 10:00, completes the task at 10:10 and next cron starts at 10:15 (every 5 minutes). but usage of 'synchronized means, the first task will start at 10:00, it would run till 10:10. irrespective of the first cron, second cron would start at 10:05. But according to the OP, even when he uses 'synchronized', the second cron starts at 10:15 which is not the desired behavior

Comment: I added log statements before and after processing the request. Timing confirms my understanding.  21:08:03 Start, 21:10:0 end 21:12:04 start 21:14:02 end.    There is a two minute gap between first cron execution end and second cron execution start.

Comment: Appologies, my 1st answer was completely off, I just updated it entirely.

Comment: In another test I changed "synchronized" with "from 00:00 to 23:00". But I observed same behavior.  In old app engine portal, I could see "every 2 minutes from 00:00 to 23:00 (UTC) " in schedule. That means my cron file is updated in GAE. I will open a issue tracker with google.

Answer (score 0):

FYI It looks like 'synchronized' is no longer part of the cron.yaml documentation. I've reached out to Google via the documentation feedback link.